# How do I disable the dynamic contrast (aka auto exposure) in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

For an example of what I'm talking about, here are two screenshots of some graffiti, taken from the exact same spot but after turning my head slightly:

[image: Bright]

[image: Dark]

This horrendous "feature" is making it extremely difficult to see anything while outdoors or near a window.  **Is there any way to disable it?**

Comment: Is this for PC?

Comment: @Joachim Yes. If there is a fix that applies to all platforms, I'm sure console players would appreciate it, but I'd imagine it's only possible on PC

Comment: No obvious answer from [PCGamingWiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Cyberpunk_2077), and the "Dev Extras Mod" it points to doesn't seem to help either. It does mention "crushed blacks" ([roughly defined here](https://www.resetera.com/threads/how-can-you-tell-when-blacks-are-crushed.164059/)) - could that be a possible part of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a mod for this on NexusMods:
https://www.nexusmods.com/cyberpunk2077/mods/2375

Comment: Based on the description, it does not remove auto-expose, it just makes it work slower (and darker for some reason, which is the opposite of what I want). Also, according to the comment it does not work with the latest version of the game.